# Prove the equivalence of two versions of FTA

Tags: polynomials

One version of the fundamental theorem of algebra states that all non-constant polynomials over $\Bbb{C}$ with complex coefficients have a zero.

The other version states that all non-constant polynomial with real coefficients factors as a product of deg 1 and deg 2 polynomials with negative discriminant.

I understand how to go from the first one to the second. How does the second imply the first? I tried to break up the coefficient into the real and imaginary part and got stuck. How should I proceed?

Comment: Once a non-constant polynomial $f$ is factored into a product of degree $1$ and $2$ polynomials, it must have a zero. If $f$ has at least one degree $1$ factor, say $(x-\alpha)$, then $\alpha$ is a zero of $f$. Otherwise, if all of its factors are degree $2$ polynomials, you could just apply the quadratic formula to obtain a (complex) root.

Comment: but 2) only applies to polynomials with real coefficient. I need the result for polynomials with complex coefficient.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $P(x)=\sum_{j=0}^n A_jx^j,$ with $n>0\ne A_n,$ let $Q(x)=\sum_{i=0}^n\bar A_jx^j.$

Observe that $P(x)Q(x)$ is a polynomial of positive degree, with real co-efficients.

The "other version" of FTA implies that $P(x)Q(x)$ factors over $\Bbb C$ as a product of deg-$1$ polynomials, so there exists $z\in \Bbb C$ with $P(z)Q(z)=0.$ Now if $P(z)=0,$ then we are done. And  if $Q(z)=0$ then $P(\bar z)=\overline {Q(z)}=\bar 0=0.$

Comment: I'm a bit confused now, why does PQ have all real coefficients?

Comment: $P(x)Q(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{2n}(x^k\sum_{i=0}^k B(i,k)\,)$ where if $i\ne k/2$ then $B(i,k)=A_i\bar A_{k-i}+A_{k-i}\bar A_i\in \Bbb R,$ and if $i=k/2$ then $B(i,k)=A_{k/2}\bar A_{k/2}\in \Bbb R.$

Answer (score 0):

Consider the complex conjugate. Multiply the polynomial with its conjugate to get a polynomial with real coefficient, then apply 2).

Comment: This will not work. E.g. $(x^3+x+i)(\bar x^3+\bar x-i)$ is not a polynomial.